# Sequelize create expecting data for a column that doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have 3 tables: `rate`, `paymentOption` and `paymentOptionRate`. When I try to execute a `bulkCreate` on `paymentOptionRate` I pass an array like this:

```js
const data = [
  {
    rateId: ccf19a9f-9897-4328-84ba-f2558fbbe10a,
    optionRateId: 9f873f92-7fbd-492e-9416-dd12f7a71dee
  },
  {
    rateId: 4329965a-89d0-46da-83f3-fbea27da8206,
    optionRateId: fae5edcc-f03e-4744-ba52-0da73406640c
  },
]
```

But for some reason I got this error:

```bash
ERROR: column "RateId" of relation "PaymentOptionRates" does not exist
```

There are my models:

- `rate`

```js
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Rate extends Model {
    static associate(models) {}
  }

  Rate.init({
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    rate: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10, 2),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    subsidiaryId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      references: {
        model: 'Subsidiaries',
        key: 'id',
      },
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      onDelete: 'SET NULL',
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Rate',
    timestamps: true,
  });

  Rate.associate(models => {
    Rate.belongsTo(models.Subsidiary, {
      foreignKey: 'subsidiaryId',
      as: 'subsidiary',
    });
    Rate.belongsToMany(models.PaymentOption, {
      through: models.PaymentOptionRate,
      foreignKey: 'rateId',
      as: 'paymentOptions',
    });
  });

  return Rate;
};
```

- `paymentOption`

```js
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class PaymentOption extends Model {
    static associate(models) {}
  }

  PaymentOption.init({
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'PaymentOption',
    timestamps: true,
  });

  PaymentOption.associate = function(models) {
    PaymentOption.belongsToMany(models.Rate, {
      through: models.PaymentOptionRate,
      foreignKey: 'paymentOptionId',
      as: 'rates',
    });
  };

  return PaymentOption;
};
```

- `paymentOptionRate`

```js
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class PaymentOptionRate extends Model {
    static associate(models) {}
  }

  PaymentOptionRate.init({
    paymentOptionId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'PaymentOptions',
        key: 'id',
      },
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    },
    rateId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'Rates',
        key: 'id',
      },
      onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'PaymentOptionRate',
    timestamps: true,
  });

  PaymentOptionRate.associate = function(models) {
    PaymentOptionRate.belongsTo(models.PaymentOption, {
      through: models.PaymentOptionRate,
      foreignKey: 'paymentOptionId',
      as: 'paymentOption',
    });
    PaymentOptionRate.belongsTo(models.Rate, {
      through: models.PaymentOptionRate,
      foreignKey: 'rateId',
      as: 'rate',
    });
  };

  return PaymentOptionRate;
};
```

I also executed this command:

```js
console.log(await PaymentOptionRate.describe());
```

And the result is:

```js
{
  paymentOptionId: {
    type: 'UUID',
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: null,
    comment: null,
    special: [],
    primaryKey: false
  },
  rateId: {
    type: 'UUID',
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: null,
    comment: null,
    special: [],
    primaryKey: false
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: 'TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE',
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: null,
    comment: null,
    special: [],
    primaryKey: false
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: 'TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE',
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: null,
    comment: null,
    special: [],
    primaryKey: false
  }
}
```

Everything seems ok, but for some reason I got this error too:

```bash
sql: 'INSERT INTO "PaymentOptionRates" ("paymentOptionId","rateId","createdAt","updatedAt","RateId") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING "paymentOptionId","rateId","createdAt","updatedAt","RateId";',
  parameters: [
    '3f5a8209-b5ae-47b1-b838-84d3dc563ecc',
    '8121ce6e-a2aa-42a0-b2a9-186227af3720',
    '2023-11-25 07:50:01.187 +00:00',
    '2023-11-25 07:50:01.187 +00:00',
    null
  ]
```

I have already executed others `bulkCreates` with other tables but just with `belongsTo` association and executed correctly but in this cases is `manyToMany` relation and I had this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use non-default foreign key column names then you need to indicate them in **all** related associations:

```js
Rate.belongsToMany(models.PaymentOption, {
      through: models.PaymentOptionRate,
      foreignKey: 'rateId',
      otherKey: 'paymentOptionId',
      as: 'paymentOptions',
    });
PaymentOption.belongsToMany(models.Rate, {
      through: models.PaymentOptionRate,
      foreignKey: 'paymentOptionId',
      otherKey: 'rateId',
      as: 'rates',
    });
```